# TextMate Bundle Document icons

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles, textmate2

I am looking for these little document icons (not only for Python) **inside** of TextMate 2.

[image: Python-Icon]

I looked in the Bundles folder of TextMate, but I couldn't find them. I really would like to use these icons as document icons in Finder.
Does anybody knows where they are located?

Fabian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/textmate/textmate/blob/master/Frameworks/OakAppKit/icons/python.icns is the source of this icon.

Other icons are below, uncovered in the search.

**TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/** is where textmate store's it's icons (version 1.5 and 2 both use the same folder).

**/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Python Launcher.app/Contents/Resources/PythonSource.icns** is where some other Python icons come from. *Note*: your version is unlikely to match my version, so replace **2.7.10_2** with the version available on your system.